# Invoking a method after a NSComboBox item value has been edited in Leopard (10.5)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I would like to invoke a method when the value in the NSComboBox is edited, precisely when the editing is finished.

I need a solution compatible with 10.5 (Leopard)
I can't use NSComboBoxDelegate because it is not supported.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSComboBoxDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSComboBoxDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
```

Comment: You'll need to set the file's owner as conforming to the protocol in the header file before it will appear in IB.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I've just realized i need a solution for Leopard (10.5). What could I do then ?

Comment: There is no way to trigger an action in when a control has been edited in OSX 10.5 ?